# Algebra books which deal with semidirect products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, semidirect-product

Out of the 8 algebra books which I've checked, I have only found 1 which deals with the semidirect product: the one by Dummit & Foote.

Are there any other books which talk about it? Thanks.

Comment: What other ones were you looking at?

Comment: @DonThousand Herstein, Gallian, Artin, Scahun, Fraleigh, and a few more

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001476/question-about-fraleigh-book-semidirect-products-and-group-action), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348429/in-need-of-a-group-theory-textbook?rq=1). There are many books treating semidirect products. I can offer [my notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_54_groups.pdf), too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: More likely to find it in a book that just does Group Theory than in a book that tries to cover all of Algebra, I think.

Comment: Why not wiki? I think this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product already contains enough information about it. Anyway it's not a complicated notion...

Comment: It seems that there is something relevant in [this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semidirect+product%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNTCuX29EafMdTQPg2I52ghWTN2NZg:1574013029869&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdnZG85_HlAhXMI7kGHZa8DB0Q_AUIGCgB&biw=1366&bih=576) (search of "semidirect product" in google books).